# Yii2 find-all + hasone

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

I have 2 tables:

```
  "article":
|id|name|text|

  "article_permissions"
|article_id|val|
```

So, I wan't to join article_permissions to **Article::find()->all();** (and filter by article_permissions::val).

I've tried to do like this:

```
Article::find()->with('articlePermissions')->all()
```

And function in ArticleModel (generated by gii):

```
public function getArticlePermissions()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ArticlePermissions::className(), ['article_id' => 'id']);
}
```

but it returns:

> *The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.* :(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are defining the relation with getArticleCategory but you are accessing it with articlePermissions. 

Also getArticleCategory would not get created by gii from articlePermissions... you are showing the wrong code.

Comment: @MihaiP. you're right. I've renamed variables in post, but I've forget to rename a function. Anyway, I have found an answer, just removing "->all();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers is to change this:

Article::find()->with('articlePermissions')->all();

TO that:
Article::find()->with('articlePermissions');

Comment: You should use some IDE to avoid a lot of things like this.